# Combo box connect in a differetn table in visual fox-pro

Tags: visual-foxpro

"I am trying to build a manual entry using a visual fox-pro. my combo box has a different categories and i want to connect it in a different table. is this possible?"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, of course, possible. Combobox have support for different type of data sources and one of them is SQL. You can write your SQL sentence as the RowSource and set RowSourceType to 3-SQL.